# Get to newly created list element on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get to newly created list elements , so I can loop through them on `submit`.

Let's Start of with `select` and empty `ul`:

```
<select name="car" id="js_car_select">
    <option value="1">BMW</option>
    <option value="2">Audi</option>
</select>

<ul id="js_car_list"></ul>
```

and some basic jQuery:

```
// Append car name to the list on select change
$('#js_car_select').on('change', function() {
    $('#js_car_list').append('<li>' + $(this).find('option:selected').text() + '</li>');
});
```

After this I have a list of cars as newly created elements.

How can I get to them on `submit`? Now when I try, none of the new `li` elements is available - `$('#js_car_list li').length` = 0.

How and where should I listen to new elements creation?

**EDIT:**

The `select` and `ul` are part of the interface. On `submit` I want to append the new list to a form as hidden `input`s, so they can be serialized with the whole form.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You mention `submit`, are you adding elements to a form? At what point in your code are you checking the length of `li` elements?

Comment: @MihaiIorga OP is appending the `li` to the `ul` - it's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace

`$('#js_car_list').append('<li>' + $(this).text() + '</li>');`

with

`$('#js_car_list').append('<li>' + $(this).find('option:selected').text() + '</li>');`

because `$(this)` refers to `<select>` element.

So, in order to append only the selected option, you have to target the selected one with `option:selected`.

Check the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8vj85x6y/)

```
$('#js_car_select').on('change', function() {
    $('#js_car_list').append('<li>' + $(this).find('option:selected').text() + '</li>');
});

$(document).on('click', '#submit', function() {
    var list = [];    
    $('#js_car_list > li').each(function() {
        list.push($(this).text());
    });
    // append the list items where ever you want .. 
    alert(list);
});
```

Comment: You're absolutely right. I edited the post. However, this is not the point. I create new list elements and I need access to them on submit.